# Conversion To prenex normal form with ∃xα ∨ ∀x(β)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The algorithm I use is the one on [this page](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/cs601/prenexAlgorithm.pdf)

But does this algorithm actually handle the following 6 cases?

- ∀x(α) ∧ ∀x(β)
- ∀x(α) ∨ ∀x(β)
- ∃x(α) ∧ ∃x(β)
- ∃x(α) ∨ ∃x(β)
- ∀x(α) ∧ ∃x(β)
- ∀x(α) ∨ ∃x(β)

If not, what are the rules for the last 2 cases?

PS: If you know a URL to some code for conversion to prenex normal form, please let me knowsince I can't find any on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

> does this algorithm actually handle the following 6 cases?

Yes; use step 3 to rname the bound variables. E.g. for : $∀x(α) ∧ ∀x(β)$, rewrite it as :

> $∀y(α) ∧ ∀x(β)$,

and then apply step 4 to get :

> > $∀y∀x(α ∧ β)$

because, after renaming, $x$ does not occur in $α$ nor $y$ in $β$.

See [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form).

---

The order of the quantifiers does not matter (in the "mixed" case) due to the renaming of bound variables.

Consider e.g.:

> $∀x(α) ∨ ∃x(β)$.

After renaming, we get : $∀y(α) ∨ ∃x(β)$; then we apply step 4 to the left $∀y$ quantifier, getting : $∀y(α ∨ ∃x(β))$, due to the fact that $y$ does not occur in $β$.

Now forget about $∀y$ for a moment and apply again step 4 with $∃x$, getting :

> $(α ∨ ∃x(β)) \equiv ∃x(α ∨ β)$

due to the fact that $x$ does not occur in $α$.

Now, we can "restore" $∀y$ to get :

> > $∀y∃x(α ∨ β)$.

The procedure is clearly symmetrical; thus, starting with $∃x$ we can get :

> $∃x∀y(α ∨ β)$.

Comment: What happens to the last 2 cases?

Comment: @Domien - it's the same : rename and apply step 4.

Comment: Does It become ∀y∃x(α∧β) or ∃x∀y(α∧β) , because that's a big difference.

Comment: @Domien - can you provide an example of the "difference" ?

Comment: α(x , y) := x is the major of city y ;

∀y∃x(α(x,y)) means for every city there is a major.
But ∃x∀y(α(x,y)) means there is a single major that is major of every city.

Comment: @Domien - but this is not our case; we have not $α(x ,y)$ but $α(x)∧β(y)$.

Comment: The equivalence holds because in $α ∧ ∃x(β) ≡ ∃x(α ∧ β)$ $x$ does not occur in $α$. This is not the case with e.g. $α(x,y) ∧ ∃x(β)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, sir. I was confused by the switching quantifiers, but now I understand that this is something completely different.